# Haskell comparing characters in a word

Tags: list, haskell, char, string-comparison

I'm trying to make a function that will check how many characters are matching in a word

1. The characters are non-repeating A-Z. The position of the letters doesn't matter

> INPUT target = "ABCDE" , attempt = "CDXYZ",
>
> OUTPUT match = 2 letters (C & D)

I've managed to write a function that compares one character in a word, but I've no clue
how to make it compare every character.

```
import Data.List
--check if a char appears in a [char]
checkForCharInAWord :: [Char] -> Char -> Bool
checkForCharInAWord wrd lt = elem lt wrd

compareChars :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Int
compareChars = ?????
```

2. I would also like to know how to count the matching characters in case of words with repeating characters, the position of the letter doesn't matter. I.e:

> INPUT target = "AAAB", attempt = "ABBB"  OUTPUT match = 2 letters (A &
> B)
>
> INPUT target = "AAAB", attempt = "AABB"  OUTPUT match = 3 letters (A,
> A & B)

3. and finally how to count the matching characters in a word, but where position is also taken into consideration

> INPUT target = "NICE", attempt = "NEAR"  OUTPUT match = 1 letters (N)
> -- correct letter and a correct position
>
> INPUT target = "BBBB", attempt = "BABA"  OUTPUT match = 2 letters (B,
> B) -- correct letter and a correct position

---

In each case I need just a simple int output with a similarity rating between 0 and (max number of letters in a target word.
The method should be flexible enough to allow words of different length (however target and attempt word will always be of equal length).

Thanks!

Comment: Hint: use `filter` and `length`.

Comment: For the second one you can work with `nub`, and for the third one with `zipWith`.

Comment: One of the main problems seems to be enumerating through the whole first list to check every element with every element in the whole second list. How could I tackle this, while keeping the code flexible, without hard-coding each expected letter position for comparison ( i.e.  x!!0 == y!!0 )?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below function seems to work for point 3. It takes two formal parameters (`w1` and `w2`) representing the two words you want to compare, creates a list of 2-tuples of the corresponding letters using the built-in zip function (`where xs = zip w1 w2` ). Then it goes through this list of 2-tuples and for each tuple compares the two elements using a list comprehension with guard. If they match, it adds a 1 to the list, otherwise it does nothing. Finaly, it sums all elements of this list (`sum [1 | x<-xs, fst x == snd x]`).

```
    match :: [Char] -> [Char] -> Int
    match w1 w2 = sum [1 | x<-xs, fst x == snd x]
        where xs = zip w1 w2
```

[image: Test output]